# about bullet under \cvlistitem

Tags: vertical-alignment

now I want to start a new section with all content with bullet in my resume using the popular modern cv templete.

```
\documentclass{moderncv}

\begin{document}

\setion{new project}

\cvlistitem{item big 1}

\begin{itemize}

\item subitem1

\end{itemize}

\cvlistitem{item big 2}

\end{document}
```

now I want to add sub bullet under each big item 1 and 2. How do I reach this?

if I do it like shown, it starts from the beginning of line without indenting

Any one help? Appreciate!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Good try (+1), but in the edited code is now a minimal, but not working example (without at least  `\firstname` and `\familyname` it is not a compilable code, and without a cv theme it is no very useful to understand  the problem) .

Answer (score 2):

One approach could be enclose the `itemize` environment in a right-aligned `minipage`:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}     %  required
\firstname{Long John}             %  required
\familyname{Silver}               %  required
\def\a{ This is a dummy text to see the linebreak in the right margin. }
\begin{document}
\section{new project}
\cvlistitem{Item big 1.\a}
\hfill\begin{minipage}{.7\linewidth} 
\begin{itemize}
\item itemize subitem 1 
\item itemize subitem 2 
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\cvlistitem{Item big 2. \a}
\end{document}
```